# Kernel writing logs every second

Tags: debian, logging, kernel

I'm looking in `/var/log/messages` and I'm seeing this sort of logging every second:

> May  5 16:54:55 dag kernel: [86219.516013] EDAC MC0: CE page 0xfe5e7,
>   offset 0x400, grain 128, syndrome 0xe0, row 4, channel 0, label "":
>   i3000 CE
>
> May  5 16:54:56 dag kernel: [86220.516020] EDAC MC0: CE page 0xfe5e7,
>   offset 0x400, grain 128, syndrome 0xe0, row 4, channel 0, label "":
>   i3000 CE

(server name is dag).

I have no idea why it's writing these logs every second and it makes tracing other problems difficult due to all the noise.

Can someone pleas tell me how to disable this or turn down the verbosity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this command made EDAC a bit more quiet:

```
echo 0 > /sys/module/edac_core/parameters/edac_mc_log_ce
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to hide hardware problems? You should replace RAM, motherboard and/or CPU as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/291632) report mentions the same and he fixed it by changing his RAM. Seems to be a hardware problem.

Comment: EDAC is Error Detection in Linux, you can find more data here, but in this case the MC means it is likely to be bad memory, or a bad motherboard/proc.  http://buttersideup.com/edacwiki/Main_Page